# fix Ip on osx without ethernet connection

Tags: macos, loopback

I amn running for development an mampwordpress server with a fix IP adress. When I am offline, without ehternet connection the server isn't usable.

how can i make a loopback or something else on osx to fake the ethernet address?

regards

Answer (score 0):

i found it:

sudo ifconfig lo0 alias IPadresse

to deactivate

sudo ifconfig lo0 -alias IPadresse